# Bootstrap panel body 100% height - flexbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to design the layout with 100% height of the viewport (minus header `height: 70px;`).

I'm able to achieve the outer layout, [see here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YS8b4DDBZA8uvaCDDtth?p=preview) and I want the panel's body also to be extend to 100% height through css (responsive).

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.6 and targeted browsers are IE11+ and latest browser's.

Please help me how I can achieve this? [I tried](http://www.bootply.com/BZQYq01ABC) but didn't help.

Comment: So, you want the panel with the content, to be the remaining size of the window - (header + footer), correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest (maybe not best) way I can think of is using viewport units and calc

```
height: calc(100vh - 70px);
```

Comment: The vh takes the document viewport height not the parent div height

Comment: I have used ```vh units and calc```. That's the only way I could figure-out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jquery - javascript

```
            $( window ).resize(function() {
                $( "div" ).css('height',($( window ).height()-70)+'px');
            });
```

Comment: I know to use jquery but I don't use jquery in the project. Basically I don't want to use script to control the size.

Comment: mmmm Bootstrap have a trick to do this, using `padding:50%` to the object, is it used on videos but the example is good and with a little thinking maybe you can use it to solve your problem. [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed)